# Why doesn't Files.isHidden() working correctly?

Tags: java, io, nio

I'm messing around with Java NIO and for some reason I can't get Files.isHidden() to return the correct boolean value. The program just checks to see if the directory is hidden then if it is hidden will make it visible and if it is not hidden it will make it hidden. This is what I have:

```
    Path start = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("E:/Documents/someDirectory");
    try {
        if (Files.isHidden(start)){
            System.out.println("Dir is hidden.");
            Files.setAttribute(start, "dos:hidden", false);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Dir is not hidden. Hiding.");
            Files.setAttribute(start, "dos:hidden", true);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It keeps returning false and hiding the directory despite the directory being hidden. The following code works fine using the old File class w/ the Path class.

```
    Path start = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("E:/Documents/someDirectory");
    File file = new File("E:/Documents/someDirectory");
    try {
        if (file.isHidden()){
            System.out.println("Dir is hidden.");
            Files.setAttribute(start, "dos:hidden", false);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Dir is not hidden. Hiding.");
            Files.setAttribute(start, "dos:hidden", true);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: What version of Windows and Java are you using?  Your code works for me on Windows 10 with the latest Java 8.  Also, do you get different results if you read from a different directory, like c:/temp for example?  Some folders may have security restrictions?

Comment: That is the exact setup I have as well. So the first snippet is working okay? Does it unhide after it is hidden?

Comment: First snippet works as you'd expect, if hidden it outputs the File is hidden and unhides it.  I see it pop in and out of visibility in File Explorer.  When re-run, it does the opposite, saying it's not hidden and hides it properly.

Comment: Just to eliminate other setup issues, sanity check all your imports come from java.nio.* ?

Comment: Correct it is using nio. It turns out that the functionality is not working for directories but only files. I will update my question to reflect that

Comment: And to add, the second snippet does work with directories as well

Comment: FWIW, Oracle's   [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#isHidden-java.nio.file.Path-) for isHidden seems to indicate this is working as intended: "On Windows a file is considered hidden if it isn't a directory and the DOS hidden attribute is set."

Comment: **Note:** This behavior [was a bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8215467) and has been fixed as of Java 13.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already pointed out in the comments, the documentation of [`Files.isHidden`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#isHidden-java.nio.file.Path-) states:

> The exact definition of hidden is platform or provider dependent. […] On Windows a file is considered hidden if it isn't a directory and the DOS hidden attribute is set.

While the last cited sentence already explains while it doesn’t return the expected value for a directory on Windows, I want to emphasize the first sentence. You are using a method burdened with a platform/provider specific semantics, while all you want to do, is to toggle a particular, platform specific flag.

In that case, you should just do exactly that, which also elides the conditionals of your code:

```
Path start=Paths.get("E:/Documents/someDirectory");
boolean isHidden=(Boolean)Files.getAttribute(start, "dos:hidden");
System.out.println("Dir is "+(isHidden? "hidden. Showing.": "not hidden. Hiding"));
Files.setAttribute(start, "dos:hidden", !isHidden);
```

Note also the convenience method `Paths.get(…)` for `FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(…)`.